# Need to change OutputField lable in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning, outputfield

in Lightning component, we are displyaing date for custom object using OutputField
Ex:

```
<lightning:outputField fieldName="ReceivedSerialNumber__c"/>
```

API label for the above field is receivedserial number.Now without change in api label name on the object level , need to change label name only for component level.any help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Kiran, you can achieve your use case with 2 changes,

1.first hide the api label name by using "variant='label-hidden'

2. you have to give custom label name before your lightning:outputfield by using label element here sample code

**cmp:**

```
 <form class="slds-form"> 
        <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="form-element-01">Shipped Asset</label> 
            <lightning:outputField variant="label-hidden" fieldName="CaseNumber" />
         </div>
        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Date_Ship_to_Customer__c"/> 
     </form>
```

[image]

Comment: :Thank you so much,its working for me.Could you please suggest the alignement.Currently its looks like this.
Shipped Asset                                           
                                  MA1216040099

Comment: @Kiran, we can give exact suggestions only if you update your question with what alignment you got now, and what alignment you want/expect.

Comment: Thanks! for your help please find the details.on table for row 1) Shipped Asset: (Empty)................we are expecting ReceivedSerialNumber__c value on same row,But the value is showing on row 2.

Comment: <div class="slds-form-element">
                     <form class="slds-form slds-form_horizontal">
                     <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="form-element-01">Shipped Asset</label>
                      <lightning:outputField variant="label-hidden" fieldName="ShippedSerialNumber__c" />
                       <!-- <lightning:outputField fieldName="ShippedSerialNumber__c"/> --> 
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Date_Ship_to_Customer__c"/>
                    </form>

Comment: @Kiran can you update your actual question with images instead add code in comments section

Comment: https://imgur.com/cDO6Y0f.   could you please check with below link

Comment: @Kiran updated my answer with your code, u can have a look if it's works do upvote to use the solution for others.

Comment: its working for me, thanks a lot for your support !

Answer (score 0):

[Lightning output field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-output-field/specification) has an attribute variant whose value can be `label-hidden`  which you can use to hide label and then use a `span or p tag` to show the label you want.

```
<lightning:outputField fieldName="ReceivedSerialNumber__c" variant='label-hidden'/>
```

Havent tried it though should work based on documentation.

Comment: Hi, could you please share me , how to add span or div tag to display custom label for the field.Since i am very new to slds & lightning please help

Comment: yes you can achieve by  variant='label-hidden' as @ResDevil said , but keep in mind variant='label-hidden' is not working for lightning:inputField from summer19 onwords

Comment: Hi Thanks .Yes i have hide the same.but my requriment is to display output field with custom name,not from API label name of field. say now i am displaying Received serial number since it is the standard label fetching and displaying,But here i need to fetech the value and display with different name

Answer (score 0):

Adding the **variant** attribute to the outputField with *label-hidden* removes the existing label. You can then add one of your own above it and style the text with [SLDS](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/)

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="0011U00000DRNkwQAH" objectApiName="myObject">
    <p class="slds-text-heading_small"><lightning:formattedText value="Company"/></p>
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="ReceivedSerialNumber__c" variant="label-hidden"/>
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

**Result**:

[image]